# Android: Intent Leaked while sending mail

Tags: android

I am trying to send a mail with some information.

I have not registered any broadcast receiver.
I have put a try catch block , if the system has no mail client, but when i click the button i get the following error-

```
    07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@413fc848 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@413fc848 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1073)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1060)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1054)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:99)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
07-22 11:03:00.727: E/ActivityThread(20107):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am just tring to send a mail from the phone and nothing else.

My main class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button sendSms, btnBackup;private String contactList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpValue();
    }
    private void setUpValue() {
        btnBackup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactBackup);
        btnBackup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
private void  sendMail(String message){

        String toReceipient="XXXX.com";
        String carbonCopy="YYYYYl.com";

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        /*Intent emainIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emainIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emainIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toReceipient);
        emainIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, carbonCopy);
        emainIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Contact List");
        emainIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, message);
        emainIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emainIntent, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        contactList = new String();
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String Name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String Number = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contactList=("Name:" + Name + " ~ " + "Contact:" + Number
                    + "\n");
        }
        Log.i("Deep", contactList);
        sendMail(contactList);

    }
}
```

And my android manifest file----

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If the phone doesnt have a mail client will this not work?

***Solution****

IT worked after i enabled a mail client.

Comment: Yes it will "work" if "run" is what you actually wanted to ask. it will simply issue a `Toast` if no mail client is installed. As for your problem, could you provide any code you have for implementations of your BroadcastReceiver? Or is this all the code you implemented?

Comment: I have not implemented a braodcast receiver. I just tried sending a mail.

Comment: It worked after i enabled a mail client

Comment: My bad. I saw the Toast and assumed you tested whether you had enabled a mail service. I believe it would be good practice to test for it before enabling the mail feature of your application.

Answer (score -1):

No its not work because it call implicit intent you can use Intent.ACTION_SEND to call an existing email client to send an Email you have to add email account to your device or emulator then use below code it compulsory required email register or you can create new one also

Refer below link for send email

www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/